# how can send array in html forms to php

Tags: php, html

I want to send uploaded files address from html to php with array and then moved the uploaded files to images from tmp and checked their size

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" action="upload.php">
  <p>

    <input type="file" name="Img[]" />
  </p>
  <p>

    <input type="file" name="Img[]" />
</p>
  <p>

    <input type="file" name="Img[]" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

```php
<?php
$name=rand('0123456789',5).'jpg';
$files=array($_POST['Img[]']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($files);

if($_FILES['$files[0]']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg'){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$files[]]['tmp_name'],'image/'.$name);
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

I want to upload files with form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input file elements never store in the `$_POST` array. You have to loop through the `$_FILES` array to get the file elements

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

    for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['Img']['tmp_name']) ; $i++) {
      $name=rand('0123456789',5);
      if($_FILES['Img']['type'][$i]  == 'image/jpeg')
      {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Img']['tmp_name'][$i],'image/'.$name . '.jpg');
      }
      echo "success";
    }
}
```

In this solution you can increase the number of input files with the same name as `Img`

Comment: thanks for your answer I had tried it. it worked but it cant upload first file

Comment: It might have `type` issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

    foreach($_FILES['Img'] as $Img) {
      $name=rand('0123456789',5);
      if($Img['type']  == 'image/jpeg')
      {
        move_uploaded_file($Img['tmp_name'],'image/'.$name . '.jpg');
      }
      echo "success";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your 3 last answers doesn't contain any explanation, just a code dump (with "Try this" at a few). That is not good answers. Explain what you did and why/how it works.